# Rename files by adding 10 - Unix

Tags: file, unix, rename

I have some files which are named as follows :

```
abc21pqr.txt
abc22pqr.txt
abc23pqr.txt
```

and so on till

```
abc1000pqr.txt
```

I want to take the number between "abc" and "pqr", add 10 to that number and rename the files :

So my output filenames should be :

```
abc31pqr.txt
abc32pqr.txt
abc33pqr.txt
```

and so on till

```
abc1010pqr.txt
```

How can I do this using a Unix one-liner ?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if both `abc23pqr.txt` and `abc33pqr.txt` exist prior to renaming?

Comment: You should also mention *which* shell you are using - there is no such thing as a *Unix* onliner...

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html

Answer (score 2):

For [GNU Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), assuming that the strings before and after the number are fixed and that all files are in the current directory:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'abc[0-9]*pqr.txt' |
    sed 's|^./abc||; s|pqr\.txt$||' |
    sort -nr |
    while read src; do
       mv abc${src}pqr.txt abc$((src+10))pqr.txt
    done
```